# Skyrim Install Problems

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Just bought a new computer and a copy of Skyrim, but the game won't install.  After I put the disk into the computer, it makes a really bad rattling noises.

I've tried installing the game using different install disks, but I still have the same problem.  I can play normal dvd's and cds just fine. My computer is literally less than 1 week old, all the drivers are up to date etc. I also don't have steam or anything like that installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it just Skyrim install discs that you are having this problem with? What about other game discs? Do the discs work on other PCs? Have you tried to get a replacement for your DVD drive from the computer vendor, as it sounds like a physical problem with the drive, which we can't really help with?

Comment: I agree, a rattling noise says that there is something wrong with the drive and/or disc. Nothing software or game related. Tell your PC supplier and see what they say.

Comment: Its just the skyrim disk.  I've installed other games, no probs and have had no problems watching dvds or listening to cds.  As soon as a put in a skyrim disk though, the problems start.  I'm new to the steam thing, do I need to have steam client installed for the computer the recognise the skyrim disk?  I've tried installing steam but I get the win 32 error 5 bug no matter what.  I don't think this is meant to be :-/

Comment: why the downvotes?

Answer (score 3):

If you are having problems with the Skyrim disc itself and have confirmed that this is not a hardware issue by using other discs in your machine and/or the Skyrim disc in another machine then a possible solution for you is as follows;

- Install Steam manually from http://store.steampowered.com/
- Create your Steam account if you do not currently have one
- Log in to Steam and access your 'Game Library'
- Click '+ Add A Game' on the Library screen
- Enter your Skyrim CD key

This should authenticate your copy of Skyrim against Steam, and allow you to download the game via Steam rather than using your installation media.